# Why do my results not stay consistent?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have the following stored procedure that I working on. I have noticed that every 5th or 6th time I refresh my results there are new values in there. Which considering that the data is in a static environment and no one is making any changes to the data at this time I really can't understand. Can someone please enlighten me as to why I would see different results even though I am running this procedure with the exact same parameters. I even tried it in query analyzer and still see the same strange results.

I am running in Sql 2008.

Here is the proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectSearchBy_Category]
    @userId     INT,
    @page       INT,
    @results        INT,
    @category       NVARCHAR(50),
    @searchTerm NVARCHAR(200) = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ROWCOUNT @results

    DECLARE @categoryId INT

    IF (@category IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
        SET @categoryId = ( SELECT categoryId FROM Category WHERE categoryDescription = @category )
    END

    DECLARE @rowEnd     INT
    DECLARE @rowStart   INT
    SET @rowEnd = (@page * @results)
    SET @rowStart = @rowEnd - @results

    ;WITH OrderedItems AS 
    (   
        SELECT
            i.itemId,
            title,
            i.[description],
            i.url,
            i.categoryId,
            i.ratingId,
            i.requirements,
            ISNULL(i.rating, 0) AS tating,
            ISNULL(i.raters, 0) AS raters,
            i.urlFriendlyPath,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
                ORDER BY i.dateAdded, (ISNULL(i.rating, 0) * ISNULL(i.raters, 0))
            ) AS RowNumber
        FROM
            [dbo].[Item] i
        LEFT JOIN
            UserItemIgnore uii ON uii.itemId = i.itemId AND uii.userId = @userId
        INNER JOIN
            ItemLanguage il ON il.itemId = i.itemId
        WHERE
            (@searchTerm IS NULL OR a.title LIKE '%' + @searchTerm + '%') AND
            i.categoryId = @categoryId AND
            il.languageId = 1 AND
            uii.itemId IS NULL
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM OrderedItems
    WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @rowStart AND @rowEnd

END
```

Comment: have you tried running sql profiler in the background, to see what else could be affecting the data?

Comment: It is running from management studio so the parameters are not ever changing there. I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Looks like I am all set. It's a toss up as both were good answers. But I think the order by on the resulting table is probably the more complete solution.

Comment: The order by on the outer table won't guarantee deterministic results!

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. I even mentioned that I could run into that. Not really thinking today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.dateAdded, 
                             (ISNULL(i.rating, 0) * ISNULL(i.raters, 0)), 
                             i.itemId)
```

`i.itemId` will act as a tie breaker to ensure that the results of `ROW_NUMBER` are deterministic in the event you have rows with equal ranks for `i.dateAdded, (ISNULL(i.rating, 0) * ISNULL(i.raters, 0))`

Comment: Will do. As there is a possibility of those being the same for those first two criteria. Thanks for the reminder on that one.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have consistent results if you put an `order by` clause in your `OrderedItems` temporary table definition.

Comment: Oh that is interesting. I didn't think about that. You are right. That is probably where the issue might be happening. Don't know why I didn't think about that.